# How to Calculate MPG miles per gallon using Classes in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hello I need help understanding C++ in dumb down term can any one help me understand how to calculate MPG using classes. this is what i have so far.
I want really want to get better but every program been kicking my but in class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cars{
    double miles;
    double gallons;
private:
    double miles[6] = {240.5, 300.0, 320.5, 280.7, 190.7, 265.3};
    double gallons[6] = {16.4, 15.6, 17.2, 15.4, 13.7, 16.9};

public:
    cars(double m, double g) : miles(m), gallons(g){}
    double mpg(void) {return miles / gallons;}
};


int main() {
    int i;
    cout << "Index\tMiles\tGallons\tMPG\n";
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        cout << i << "\t" << miles[i] << "\t" << gallons[i] << endl;
    }
    char z; cin >> z;
}
```

without Classes I got

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    double miles[6] = {240.5, 300.0, 320.5, 280.7, 190.7, 265.3};
    double gallons[6] = {16.4, 15.6, 17.2, 15.4, 13.7, 16.9};
    float mpg[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int i;

    float mpgCal(){
        cout << mpg = miles/gallons;
        return mpg;

    }

int main() {
    cout << "Index\tMiles\tGallons\tMPG\n";
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        cout << i << "\t" << miles[i] << "\t" << gallons[i] << "\t" << mpg[i] << endl;
    }
    char z; cin >> z;
}
```

Comment: your structure of class doesnt look correct. You have saved all miles,gallons data in the class and havent created any objects. Isn't it giving you compile time error?

Comment: If you need help with compiler errors you should include them in the question. To calculate miles per gallon all you need is `mpg = miles / gallons;`

Comment: `class cars` probably should be `class car` and get rid of the arrays in the class. Then you should have an array of car in your main.

Comment: In C++ and OOP, the for loop you currently have in main,  might be best moved  to a new method of class cars, perhaps "cars::show()." Encapsulation is the idea ... in main, you need to 'instance' an object of type cars, perhaps call it car, then simply invoke car.show().  This resolves the access by the function to your data.

Comment: an admonishment to downvoters of this question.... he gave it a shot and then asked for help, which we should encourage. also, I've changed my mind on the homework help topic... if SO questions are basically "please do my work for me" questions, what is the difference if that "work" happens to be assigned by a school other than an employer?

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;


 double miles[6] = {240.5, 300.0, 320.5, 280.7, 190.7, 265.3};
 double gallons[6] = {16.4, 15.6, 17.2, 15.4, 13.7, 16.9};
 float mpg[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
 int i;

 float mpgCal(){
  cout << mpg = miles/gallons;
  return mpg;

 }

int main() {
    cout << "Index\tMiles\tGallons\tMPG\n";
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
  cout << i << "\t" << miles[i] << "\t" << gallons[i] << "\t" << mpg[i] << endl;
    }
    char z; cin >> z;
}

Comment: You should ask Volkswagen. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: did not compile this, as I have no compiler handy ATM.

You need an array of cars, not of doubles. Your class needs to expose a way to get miles and gallons.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class car{
private:
    double miles;
    double gallons;
public:
    car(double m, double g) : miles(m), gallons(g){}
    double getMPG(void) const {return miles / gallons;}
    double getMiles(void) const {return miles;}
    double getGallons(void) const {return gallons;}
};

car cars[6]={ 
    car(240.5, 16.4), 
    car(300.0, 15.6), 
    car(320.5, 17.2), 
    car(280.7, 15.4), 
    car(190.7, 13.7), 
    car(265.3, 16.9)};

int main() {
    int i;
    cout << "Index\tMiles\tGallons\tMPG\n";
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        cout << i << "\t" << cars[i].getMiles() << "\t" << cars[i].getMiles() << "\t" << cars[i].getMPG() << endl;
    }
    char z; cin >> z;
}
```

Comment: Thank you This one help me understand I did not know i had to return values for classes and the i did not know a can write a array like that.

Comment: truth be told, @ingconti provided an answer that is "righter" than mine, and does it the "right way". However, based on where I perceive you are at in learning, that doesn't really matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

you code is a bit messy.
If You want to use the concept of Car, your class myst be "Car".
Or do you want to create a class member to calculate MPG?

I think You should think in these term:

- a Car is an abstract concept
- we can create 6 instances of Car
- now we have an array of car
- let cycle it and ask for every Car to show its MPG.

What kind of C++ do You want to use?

C++11 on what compiler?

anyway:

MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Car.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    const int MAX = 2;

    Car cars[MAX] = {
        Car(240.5,16.4),
        Car(300.0,15.6),
    };


    int i;
    cout << "Index\tMiles\tGallons\tMPG\n";
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        Car c = cars[i];
        cout << i << "\t" << c.getMiles() << "\t" << c.getGallons()<< "\t" << c.mpg() << endl;
    }
    char z; cin >> z;

    return 0;
}
```

car.h

```
class Car{
private:

    double miles;
    double gallons;

public:
    Car(double m, double g);
    double mpg(void);

    double getMiles();
    double getGallons();


};
```

car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"




Car::Car(double m, double g)
{
    miles = m;
    gallons = g;

}


double Car::mpg(void)
{
    double d = miles / gallons;
    return d;
}



double Car::getMiles(void)
{
    return miles;
}



double Car::getGallons(void)
{
    return gallons;
}
```

output:

Index   Miles   Gallons  MPG

0      240.5    16.4     14.6646

1      300      15.6     19.2308